# Javascript getUint16 alternate for Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, byte

I have this JavaScript code. For reading out BLE value.

```
         ble.read(currentDevice,"49141400-61EE-46BF-858C-6872C0C9A710","4914140b-61EE-46BF-858C-6872C0C9A710",function(data) {
         var dv1 = new DataView(data);
         document.getElementById("profile71").value = dv1.getUint16(0,true);
         document.getElementById("profile72").value = dv1.getUint16(2,true);
         document.getElementById("profile73").value = dv1.getUint16(4,true);
         document.getElementById("profile74").value = dv1.getUint16(6,true);
         document.getElementById("profile75").value = dv1.getUint16(8,true);
         document.getElementById("profile76").value = dv1.getUint16(10,true);
         },app.OnError);
```

Search alternate for Swift 3.0. I don't know how I can translate Uint16 from data.

I use in Swift: BLE characteristic.value

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have data of type `Data` in dv1:

```
var dv1: Data? = Data() // Rather `Data()`, you will your your data here

// Do this to convert dv1 to `UInt16`
if let data = dv1 {
    let u16Array: [UInt16] = data.bytes // `u16Array` is of type [UInt16] 
}
```

Where `bytes` lies in `Data` extension as:

```
extension Data {
    public var bytes: Array<UInt16> {
        return Array(self)
    }
}
```

Comment: I did it for `UInt8` for decrytion purposes.